# Javascript for json object nothing shows in the html page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm following a JS tutorial, and I've faced a problem: the list is not showing in my browser.

I checked the script part, but it's all okay. I didn't find the error in my code.

The output on my page's browser should be somthing like this list:

```
*facebook:...
*instagram:...
```

Script:

```
var info= {
  "full_name": "tim berner ",
  "tile": "staff author",
  "links": [
    {"facebook": "https://web.facebook.com/"},
    {"instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/"}
  ]
};

var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= info.length; i++){
  for (key in info.links[i]){
    if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)){
      output += '<li>' +
        '<a href= "' + info.links[i] [key] + 
        ' ">' + key + '</a> ' +
        '</li>' ; 
    } //hasOwnProperty
  } //for each object
} //for each array element 

var update = document.getElementById('links');
update.innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `.links` in the for statement condition. See working JavaScript code below:

```
var info = {
    "full_name": "tim berner ",
    "tile": "staff author",
    "links": [
        { "facebook": "https://web.facebook.com/" },
        { "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/" }
    ]
};

var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= info.links.length; i++) {
    for (key in info.links[i]) {
        if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            output += '<li>' +
                '<a href= "' + info.links[i][key] +
                ' ">' + key + '</a> ' +
                '</li>';
        }//hasOwnProperty
    }//for each object
}//for each array element 
var update = document.getElementById('links');
update.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I forgot to add <h2>Links</h2> <ol id="links">  before the script tag , now it works !

Comment: The mistake was in the first for statement: info.length is undefined. info.links.length is what you meant